# The text in my math formula is too long, and the known solutions are to solve the too long math formula……

Tags: latex

[image: formula]

Does anyone know how to type this formula in latex?
I searched for a long time on the Internet and read the book, but did not find a relevant solution

I try align or multline,They just wrap my formula, and I want to just let them do it like in the screenshot

```
\begin{aligned}
    \text{CPU execution time for a program} &= \\
    \text{CPU clock cycles for a program} \times \text{Clock cycle time}
\end{aligned}
```

The above is an example of an error

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

`align` is meant for typesetting math expressions.

In this case, you should rather use [tabular](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment) with 5 columns for each term in the table. You should get familiar with this environment and making table in LaTeX in general. One difficulty could be with those multi line cells. This is well handled by an old package [makecell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell)--the manual is available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/).

Here's the code. In the last cell, `\raisebox{}{}` is to vertically centre \times symbol with the content (might require your adjustment).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} *5{c} @{}}
  \makecell{CPU execution time\\for a program}
  & $=$
  & \makecell{CPU clock cycles\\for a program}
  & $\times$
  & \raisebox{-0.15ex}{Clock cycle time}
\end{tabular}
\par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]